# Can't get JOIN statement to return results

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

I'm actually trying to use JOINS for the first time and I'm having a tough time getting it to go. I have two tables...stories and wp_users and I'm trying to return all stories and include the display_name of the user from users along with each story.

This code works fine to get all results from stories and show story name and genre:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM stories where stories.active = 1");
foreach ($results as $row) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $row->story_name; '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->genre; '</td>';
```

Now I want to also include the name of the user who wrote the story ("display_name" from wp_users table)

After reading many sites about joins the below approach seemed best, but sadly it returns no results:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT stories.story_name, stories.genre, wp_users.display_name as display FROM
stories LEFT JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID=wp_users.ID where stories.active = 1";

$results = $wpdb->query($sql);

if($results->num_rows) {
while($row = $results->fetch_object())  {
echo "{$row->story_name} {$row->genre} {$row->display}<br>";
}
}
else  {
echo 'No results';
}
```

Comment: probably error with the join. try `$results = $wpdb->query($sql) or die($wpdb->error);` to see the error message.

Comment: I'm sure it's a problem with the join since it was returning results until my join statement. I added the die code and all it says is "No results"

Comment: This will only return a result if a userid = a storyid I assume you want a userid to = storycreatorid or something similar

Comment: Yes, I want the user ID (which is just "ID" in users table) to match the user ID in the stories table (which is also "ID"). There is also a story ID field SID but I'm not touching that here. Why do you say it will only show results if userid = a storyid

Comment: It does seem odd that a column called id in a table called stories should correspond to a column called id in a table called user, but hey, it's your schema, and you've chosen not to show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions that might help:

1. In your first code snippet, you are using `$wpdb->get_results()` while in your second snippet there is `$wpdb->query()`. There might be some difference in the returned value and the meaning of the parameters.
2. Find out about the method that asks for error messages after querying and use it to dump the message. Often if no rows are returned it is because there was an error.
3. Make sure `num_rows` really is got from `$results`. Here (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class) it says the expression is `$wpdb->num_rows`. (You'll find it by searching the site for 'num_rows', it'll scroll down.)
4. Try to use the MySQL Command Shell or some PhpMyAdmin sandbox to check the query. Entering the SQL directly will show typos and other problems like "unknown column" in the SQL code, and it allows to edit fast. Joining syntax varies between databases, yet your `LEFT JOIN` is ok to MySQL. There seems to by no problem on the syntactic level.

This docu http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class may help to come clear with the code.

Comment: I did peruse the codex; sadly so little to no info on joins with $wpdb. I suppose it could be something related to No. 1 in your response. I was worrying about getting to this join issue since I started this site and sure enough it's very challenging

Comment: Usually, where you can use a full but simple `SELECT` SQL statement, you can also use a joined SQL statement. It is not that difficult :-) Maybe you are making too big steps. Go back to your first snippet that worked fine, run it again to check it still works, and then alter *only* the SQL statement, replace it with the JOINed statement. If this still works fine, try iterating the result set. That way you can observe what step causes problems.

Comment: Got it! Just posted answer. Thanks for thoughts and help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT stories.story_name, stories.genre,
wp_users.display_name FROM stories LEFT JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID=wp_users.ID where  
stories.active = 1");

if ($results) {
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>Story Name</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>Genre</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>Last User on this Website to See</b></td>';
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($results as $row) {

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $row->story_name; '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->genre; '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->display_name; '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```